# Fitting long text from a text-file on an LC-Display via Python and a Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, file, raspberry-pi, display, lcd

Here's the SHORT version of my problem and what I want:

1. Read text from a file
2. Format the text to display it on a 4x20 LCD with *readable* newlines if a line is too long (e.g. look how long the line is (max 20 characters), make a newline at last found whitespace character)
3. If text overall is too long (more than 80 characters) display first 80 characters on the display - clear display - show remaining characters -repeat multiple times.

*And here's the long version ;)*

I'm a **beginner in programming** and currently I'm working on a little home project where I want to use a Raspberry Pi 3 together with an GSM HAT (from Waveshare) to display a received SMS on an LC-Display. After receiving the SMS (using "Gammu-SMS Daemon"), the SMS gets stored as .txt file in a folder on my RPi. From there I want to read it via a python script and display it in an formatted way on an LCD. So far nothing very complicated I thought. Where I struggle now (for over a week already) is to print a long SMS text on my Display. Using the RPLCD lib and communicating via I2C with my Display my code so far looks like this:

```
# Description: Read text from received SMS Textfile and print it on an 
# 4x20 LCD Screen

from __future__ import print_function
import os
import glob
import sys
import time
from time import *
import textwrap
from RPLCD.i2c import CharLCD

# setting up the parameters for the lcd. For standard use only the first two arguments are 
# needed
lcd = CharLCD(i2c_expander="PCF8574", address=0x27,port=1,cols=20,rows=4,
              dotsize=8,charmap="A02",auto_linebreaks=True,backlight_enabled=True)

# open last received SMS file:
list_of_files = glob.glob('/home/pi/sms_inbox/*.txt')
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)


with open(latest_file, "r") as file:
  data = file.read() 
  # print to LCD. If data is too long, text starts to 
  # print from top to bottom again over existing characters 
  lcd.write_string(data)


file.close()
```

This works as long as the text from the file is not longer than 4x20 = 80 characters long obviously. If the text is longer than that, new characters place themselfs over the first characters in the first line of the display. Not accaptable of course. 
What I did next was to use the `textwrap` lib to format it to a max. of 20 characters per line. I added this and my output on the terminal via the `print` function looked very promising. Then I thought, I can save this new formatted text in a new file and read it again to have the perfect text width. But my LCD doesn't thought the same about that. Maybe because there's a lot going on in the file with strange, not visible characters? Here's the enhanced code:

```
# Description: Read text from received SMS Textfile and print it on an 
# 4x20 LCD Screen

from __future__ import print_function
import os
import glob
import sys
import time
from time import *
import textwrap
from RPLCD.i2c import CharLCD

# setting up the parameters for the lcd. For standard use only the first two arguments are 
# needed
lcd = CharLCD(i2c_expander="PCF8574", address=0x27,port=1,cols=20,rows=4,
              dotsize=8,charmap="A02",auto_linebreaks=True,backlight_enabled=True)

# open last received SMS file:
list_of_files = glob.glob('/home/pi/sms_inbox/*.txt')
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)


with open(latest_file, "r") as file:
  data = file.read() 
  # print to LCD. If data is too long, text starts to 
  # print from top to bottom again over existing characters 
  lcd.write_string(data)

  # open a new file here. Save new formated text in there
  processed_file = open("/home/pi/processed_sms/processed_sms.txt","w")

  # shorten each line of text to a max. of 20 characters. 
  # This does NOT cut a word in the middle, it makes a newline 
  # on a found whitespace character found before the word which is too long:
  wrapper = textwrap.TextWrapper(width=20) 
  wordlist = wrapper.wrap(text = data)

  for element in wordlist:
    print(element) 
    # save new formatted file   
    processed_file.write(element)
    processed_file.write("\n")    

file.close()
processed_file.close()

# open formated file again and try to display it on the LCD (doesent work properly!)
processed_file_read = open("/home/pi/processed_sms/processed_sms.txt","r")

new_data = processed_file_read.read()
# display show weird formating, it's not readable!
lcd.write_string(new_data)

processed_file_read.close()
```

The new file was not readable for my LCD, the text was completely off regarding lines, spacing and everything else. Impossible to read! I also tried some self made algorythms to format the text but it's not that easy for me as **beginner in programming**, escpecially in python. So the whole trick is to format and place the text, as I said already multiple times, in a way, in which it can fit the display. If the text is too long, it should display the first 80 characters, clear the display and show the remaining ones. Then I would like to repeat this a couple of times. This can't be this hard, or what do YOU think?

Can you please help me? This would be so great! I want to go to bed early in the next day's :D.
TANKS already!

Comment: When you say "weird formatting" it sound "incorrect encoding". CharLCD may only be able to handle ASCII or some limited set of characters. Your processed file may be encoded differently ? One thing to explore maybe.

Comment: That is maybe right. I had some problems recently after setting up my pie from ground up new with opening text files where it said "no valid UTF-8 format found..." After that I set the system locals settings to english (GB) with UTF-8 text encoding. Then the files opened correctly without warning. But I got still the same lcd "weirdness".

Comment: I found out, that I had to add "\r\n" to processed_file.write("\r\n") when saving the new formatted file (\n, moves down 1 line and carriage return \r, moves to beginning of
line)! Now the LCD shows the text with correct newlines! Still the problem to show the SMS content on seperate "pages" of the display if the SMS Text is too long and it also doesen't show german letters like ü ä ö, but the read file and the one I save new is formatted in utf8 .... –